# Types of receptors on a single synapse or neuron

Tags: neuroscience, neurophysiology

I have been googling and couldn't find the answer to these questions.

1. For a given synapse, can a post-synaptic neuron have multiple types of receptors for different neurotransmitters or is typically just one type of receptor for a given synapse?
2. For a given post-synaptic neuron, comparing across its dendrite synapses, can it have multiple types of receptors across different synapses or is it typically just one type of receptor for a given neuron?
3. Do the quantity and types of receptors on a neuron change over time?

Thank you - much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. One synapse can have different types of receptors for the same neurotransmitter (NT) (example: Glutamate - most glutamatergic synapses have both AMPA and NMDA types of receptors). Synapses can also have receptors for different neurotransmitters (see [link](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK10818/)).
2. One neuron can also have different types of synapses which operate with different NT. An example of that would be shunting inhibition, when first comes excitatory synapse (NT - Glu), which depolarizes the membrane, but AP propagation is stopped by the inhibitory synapse (NT - GABA) which comes later. [image: see picture]

Hope it helps, I am also just a beginner :)